# In erpnext can we rename the 'Draft' of a Doctype?

Tags: state, erpnext

In material request doctype, after the action 'Submit' the state is changed to 'Draft'. I want that to be renamed to 'Under Review' instead of 'Draft'.

I wanted to change the backend code for that. But I thought I might ask you if there is another way to do it.